# Nintex Workflow not in repository

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

When I try to view a nintex workflow in Sharepoint2010, I get an error `Error Occurred. Unable to preview workflow.`
When I click edit then, I get an error: `Error Cannot find workflow in repository`.
I get `Sharepoint Designer can not display the item` when I try that with Sharepoint Designer.

When I look in to the Sharepoint logs. I see this error:

> (https://workspace.customer.com/_layouts/NintexWorkflow/Preview.aspx?WorkflowId=ba41a315-0536-474e-a719-aa5dc4ea8da9&ListId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000): Nintex.Workflow.NWException: Nintex.Workflow.NWException: Cannot find workflow in repository.
>    at Nintex.Workflow.WorkflowRepository.get_Item(Guid wfId)
>    at Nintex.Workflow.ApplicationPages.WorkflowDesigner.RenderNintexWorkflow(Guid workflowId, Guid listId, WorkflowRenderStyle style, FileVersion version, WorkflowSource source, WorkflowType category, WorkflowMetaData& details, Scope& publishScope)
>    at Nintex.Workflow.ApplicationPages.WorkflowDesigner.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) (Build:2004

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading Nintex and Nintex database to the newest version.